# Math notation for expressions using logical (binary) masks on images (matrix)

Tags: notation, matlab

I need to write up what I have written in matlab:

I have an image (that is, a matrix) $K$ and some other matrix of the same size $M$ which acts as a mask which represents the values I would like to use in some expression.

e.g. to use a simple example:

> > > K = magic(4)
>
> K =
>
> ```
> 16     2     3    13
>  5    11    10     8
>  9     7     6    12
>  4    14    15     1
> ```
>
> > > M = logical([0 0 1 0; 0 1 0 0; 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0])
>
> M =
>
> ```
>  0     0     1     0
>  0     1     0     0
>  0     0     0     0
>  0     0     0     0
> ```
>
> > > max(K(M))
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> 11
> ```

1. What is the usual standard math notation for expressing masks used in texts/journals?
2. What is the notation for the last command using argmax?
3. How would they look using a single index $i$ versus $(x,y)$ type indexes?

Hope that is clear!

Comment: This sounds like an indicator function, something like $S_{ij}=K_{ij}\delta_{ij}$ where $\delta_{ij}$ is a function that is 1 if some condition is true or 0 is some condition is false. For example $\delta_{ij}=1$ if $i,j=1,3$ or $2,2$ and 0 otherwise. Hopefully that gives you something to think about.